# How do I open a document in split screen-full screen from the terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, shell, pdf

I use a Mac and have been getting into navigating through the terminal as I prepare to switch to linux for good in the future. One annoyance I have come across, which I can't seem to figure out is how to open documents in split-screen full-screen from the terminal.

Example: 
So I usually have the terminal open in full screen mode all the time and I write my work in LaTeX in vim as well. I work with a lot of PDF documentation and do not wish to keep changing desktops to view them. 
`open xy.pdf`
opens it in a floating window of Preview. Is it possible to use flags or a different commmand to open it in split screen next to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and switch to Linux, then you can use a tiling WM like i3 or xmonad.  These will provide your desired behavior when you open a new app even when you are using terminal and desktop apps in the same workspace.

I want to say, good for you spending more time in the terminal.  I normally have 4-6 terminals open and various tmux sessions on my laptop interwoven with connections to servers.  I really think that Linux and BSD are simply amazing for this kind of work flow.

If you are already pretty comfortable, then there is no reason to prepare more before switching to Linux.  If you do want to prepare for longer before switching, then I suggest installing bash ver 5.x with brew if you don't have it yet.  You will have access to it when you switch to Linux.

PS. tmux is amazing and you should check it out if you haven't.  You can use vi like keybindings too.